# Unable to create websockets with django

Tags: python, django, websocket

I have a django server that at the moment i am running on my local machine, the django server handles WSGI requests at the moment via http but i would also like to connect with websockets.i have tried many guides online but they all result with the websocket connection returning a 404. Any help would be appreciated.

Project Structure:

```
myProject
   myApp
```

myProject.urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("server/", include("myApp.urls")),
]
```

myProject.asgi

```
import os

import django
from channels.http import AsgiHandler
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, get_default_application


os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myProject.settings")
django.setup()


application = get_default_application()
```

myProject.routing

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from myApp.consumers import PracticeConsumer
from django.urls import path

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
            URLRouter([path("five/", PracticeConsumer())])
        )
    }
)
```

myProject.settings (relevant parts)

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "myProject.asgi.application"

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer",
    },
}

WSGI_APPLICATION = "myProject.wsgi.application"
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "storages",
    "channels",
    "myApp",
]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

myApp.consumers

```
import asyncio
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer


class PracticeConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        # Handle received WebSocket message here
        await self.send(text_data=text_data)
```

let me know if there is anything else needed

i tired connecting to the websocket with
`ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/five/");`
but that resulted in the error
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/help/' failed:` 
and the inital ws promise is as follows

```
WebSocket {url: 'ws://localhost:8000/help/', readyState: 0, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
binaryType: "blob"
bufferedAmount: 0
extensions: ""
onclose: null
onerror: null
onmessage: null
onopen: null
protocol: ""
readyState: 3
url: "ws://localhost:8000/help/"}
```